# Why my Magento just send order emails using the Send Email button?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cron, transactional-mail

I have my cron configured, but my order emails are sent just when I click on the **Send Email** button.

[image: Magento2 admin panel send email button]

How could I have my emails send via schedule?

Comment: I would suggest please check the logs, then only you will get an idea, what is an issue.